# Создать несколько разделов на флешку

Tags: настройки

Здравствуйте. Хочу создать несколько разделов на флэшке но когда запускаю `fdisk - l`  то флэшка выводиться как `sdb1`. После создание нескольких разделов и монтировании их флешка вновь выводиться как `sdb1`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно создать разделы на флэшке

Answer (score 1):

Ваша флешка это /dev/sdb ! Запускайте fdisk -l /dev/sdb и увидите ее таблицу разделов, среди которой будет как минимум /dev/sdb1. Ну а что б ее поменять, fdisk /dev/sdb ну а там уже разберетесь.

Answer (score 1):

Может вам проще использовать [gparted](http://gparted.org) для этого?

Answer (score 1):

Не забывайте после создания разделов в `fdisk` выполнить команду `w` - записать измененную таблицу на диск.

Команда `parted` обладает несоклько отличным от `fdisk` фукнционалом, поддерживает таблицы разделов GUID, позволяет не задумываться о размещении разделов на границах виртуальных "цилиндров" и "секторов", позволяет без труда создавать разделы объёмом в десятки терабайт (у `fdisk` здесь есть ограничения), а также вносит изменения на диск сразу же после выполнения каждой из команд.

Answer (score 0):

Флешка обычно трактуется системой как съёмный носитель, типа дискеты (если кто помнит). Поэтому по умолчанию там виден лишь перевый раздел. Как это исправить, описано здесь: http://gromr1.blogspot.ru/2012/01/bootice.html Кроме того, заслуживает внимания комментарий Dmitri Chubarov - делать разделы не MBR, а GUID. Сам, правда, на флехах не пробовал.